# Write a recursive function to find sum of even numbers from 2 to 50 in c language

Tags: c, recursion

So far i got this. But i am getting this error :
"Undefined references to `WinMain@16' " 
Please help.

```
int sumEvensRecursively(int no1, int no2)
{
no1=5;
no2=20;
if (no1 % 2 == 1)
{
return sumEvensRecursively(no1+ 1, no2);
}

return no1+ sumEvensRecursively(no1+ 2, no2);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues wrong:

- the function is recursive on all control paths, you need a stop condition.
- it appears you pass `no1` and `no2` as parameters, yet you assign them values on the next lines. What's the point?
- the error you're getting is because you're probably compiling on windows, where the `main()` is declared something like `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])` and not `int main(int argc, char* args[])`.

tl;dr- 
**Conclusion:**

Change the `main` method in your program to `int wmain` or  `int _tmain` to solve the compiler error.

Change the algorithm to get it to actually work.

Answer (score 2):

You are always resetting your `no1` to 5 in your function. So this will run forever.

Comment: +1 though it won't run *forever*. Just until a *stackoverflow* happens. Get it?

Comment: @Linus With the right flags and compiler, it will run forever. The relevant part of assembly `gcc -O3 -foptimize-sibling-calls` produced is: `.L2: jmp .L2`. Sorry to ruin your pun.

Comment: I'll take a lesson learned over a ruined pun any time. Thanks, @Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

This is an infinite recursion. You don't have a base case when the recursion should stop.

Comment: true, but it doesn't say anything about the error he's getting.

Answer (score 0):

This function will do:

```
recur(int sum, int i){
    if(i <= 50){
        sum = sum + i;
        return recur(sum, (i+2));

    }
    else
        return sum;

}
```

Initial values for the parameters are 0, 2. So call the recur function as

```
recur(0,2);
```